# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while returning Kafka results

Tags: java, apache-kafka, talend

i'm developping a custom Talend component in Java to read data from a Kafka topic, my goal is to process these data in real time and write them into a file.

My Java code is working when the data I got are not too big, otherwise I get this error:

[JAVA ERROR: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j4PG.png)

I understood that the data I sent are too big so I have 2 questions:

- is there a way to increase the maximal size of data I send ?
- How can I optimize my code: in the code below I'm able to count the number of lines I got from Kafka in each polls, I thought that I could split the data (for example 10 per 10) but the problem is that I can use "return" only once, and that's why I sent everything after my loop.

Here is my Java code:

```
@Producer
    public Record next() {
        while (true){
            ConsumerRecords<String, Object> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
            System.out.println("new poll");
            ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
            Integer count = 0;
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : records) {
                count ++;
                String current_line = record.value().toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(current_line);
                 test = jsonObject.get("type").toString();
                 elements.add(current_line);
                 System.out.println("in= " + test);
        }
            System.out.println("count = " + count.toString());

             if (elements.size()>0) {
                 return builderFactory.newRecordBuilder().withString("name", elements.toString()).build();
             }
            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help,

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: Hello Thomas , did you tried to increase your JVM parametres and see if the issue persists

Comment: Thank you @AmineBenKhelifa, you were right, increase the RAM memory solved the problem, thank you :)

Comment: you can mark the topic as solved , if this was the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the memory and JVM settings
To gain in performance at runtime and when launching Talend Studio you can edit the memory settings in the .ini file.

By default, the .ini file sets the following JVM parameters:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize512m
-vmargs
-Xms64m
-Xmx768m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/talend.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

With 8 GB of memory available on 64-bit system, the optimal settings can be:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize512m
-vmargs
-Xms2014m
-Xmx4096m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8